# org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms, wildfly-10

I have a application that uses the above class to listen on a configured JMS queue in WildFly ( 10.1.0 )

```
<bean id="requestMessageListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
    depends-on="transactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="queueName" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestinationResolver" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="RequestMessageListener" />
    <property name="messageSelector" value="ID='RX_ID'" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>
```

The application gets deployed successfully. 
When a message is written to the queue with Msg Selector set to "RX_ID", I would expect this listener to be called.

Is there a way of confirming that the MessageListener is polling the queue.
I have configured the log4j for the Spring packages to "debug" and there is no output.

Just to confirm, my application does get deployed  in Wildfly with no errors.

Thank you.
Pete

Comment: Edit the question to show the publishing code. The container doesn't poll the queue, it polls the client library for messages sent by the broker. TRACE level logging will show that activity.

Comment: Hi Gary. Thank you for the quick response.  The publishing code, I presume you want to see how the message is written to the queue. That is via a utility program. I can see the message count for the JMS Queue increment accordingly, so I am confident that the message is on the JMS queue.
I used the steps suggested in the link below :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488230/org-springframework-jms-listener-defaultmessagelistenercontainer

Comment: So the message is on the Queue but just not  being read by MessageListener unfortunately,

Comment: Right. But does it have the ID property set properly to match the selector? Try removing the selector to test basic connectivity.

Comment: Sorry I provided the wrong link above to verify message header info. 
It should have been

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276792/wildfly-10-jms-message-content

to confirm the ID property is set.

Comment: Just an update
Appear the build process ( gradle) to generate the war file may be at fault.

I have another war file for the same application but built using Ant.

Whilst the generated war files deploy successfully, the behavior of the one generated via gradle is not as expected.

So will be investigating this.